# How to ignore all headers in ESP8266 response?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm having trouble with the response of my server. I need to ignore all those headers in the response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Status: 200 OK

Balance:50
```

```cpp
uint32_t len = wifi.recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 10);
if (len > 0) {
  Serial.print("Received:[");
  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)buffer[i]);
  }
  Serial.print("]\r\n");
}
```

Comment: The HTTP specification says that the delimiter between the headers and body is `\r\n\r\n`, so discard all input up to and including those characters and then you'll be at the start of the body.

Comment: @par can you give me a hint how can I do that?

Comment: Try looking at the loop function in [this example](https://github.com/imjosh/espLedDimmer/blob/master/arduino/espLedDimmer/espLedDimmer.ino) which reads a web page to set the brightness of an LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I put all response in String variable then find the index of my trigger ("OK" I can also use "\r\n\r\n" but I dunno why I'm using my own trigger lol) so I can filter all of those headers.

```
wifi.send((const uint8_t*)httpPost, strlen(httpPost));
int t = 0;
char resp[] = {};
uint32_t len = wifi.recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1024);
if (len > 0) {
  String resp;
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     resp += String((char)buffer[i]);
  }
  Serial.println(resp);

  int ind = resp.indexOf("OK",20);
  String response;
  for(int x = ind+3;x<=resp.length();x++){
    response += resp[x];
  }
  Serial.println(response);
 }
```